# Facebook Javascript API will Publish Album, but not finish image upload

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-canvas

Okay,

So I'm trying to upload an image to a user's profile, using the JavaScript SDK by Facebook. Essentially, I have it working—but not all the way.

It will add an album to my photos using the App Title, which is what I want. However, it won't add the photo to the album provided in the URL parameter. See below:

```
// Create the album and add the image
FB.api(
    "/me/photos",
    "POST",
{
    "url": "https://[VALID URL]"
},
function (response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        // Log the error
        console.log(response.error);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```

Like I said, something is working, because the album is showing up in my profile. But I get this error returned in the console:

```
Object {message: "An unknown error has occurred.", type: "OAuthException", code: 1}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**: I figured it out. See the explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, gotta love the run-arounds.

So my problem was not creating an album first, and then posting to that album in the response function. So the final (working) code, looks like this:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/albums",
    "POST",
    {
        "name": "[Album Name]",
        "message": "[Test Message]"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error);
      } else {
        // Get the album ID we just created
        var albumID = response.id;
        FB.api(
            "/" + albumID + "/photos",
            "POST",
            {
                message: "Test message",
                url: "[IMG URL]",
                no_story: true
            },
            function (response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log(response.error);
              } else {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.id);
              }
            }
        );
      }
    }
);
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks Calvin Koepke It worked for me too. Actually I want to know that by this code the album is created and images are also uploaded to the album but I want to know how to publish this album via graph API. It displays only in notification that the album is created and images are uploaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating albums and photos is a two step process in Graph API. First you create an album, like so:

```
$album_create = $facebook->api("/me/albums", 'POST', $album_params);
```

Then you can look to see if there' an ID in the response:

```
if (!array_key_exists('id', $album_create)) 
  return; //album not uploaded, may be an error
```

Then you post on the $album_create['id']/photos edge to post the photos.

The above calls are in php, but you should be able to convert that to JS easily.

Comment: So I originally created an album first, and then added the photo, but it the second API call would create a secondary album. Is that because I wasn't looking for an existing album first?

Comment: you can upload to both an existing album or a newly created. All you need to post photos is an album ID.